# In PubMed results sometimes there are no links to read the article?

Tags: research

In PubMed results sometimes there are no links to read the article.
For example https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23009275/
Why is this?

Comment: I think you need to ask PubMed to be sure, but I suspect the most likely explanation is simply because the article isn't available online. They can't give you a link to something that doesn't exist. That article does provide a PMID, which will allow you to find the article in print form.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @CareyGregory you need to speak to PubMed about that. I have noticed that recently too with quite a few articles.

The one linked can actually be read at https://www.ajmc.com/view/a09_12aug_rls_sethi as it is open access.

Going off tangent a little, interestingly the author information is weird to me too as there are only 2 authors, and 2 authors don't make an *et al.* citation as far as I am aware. The citation for this article is

Sethi, K. D., & Mehta, S. H. (2012). A clinical primer on restless legs syndrome: what we know, and what we don't know. *The American journal of managed care, 18*(5 Suppl), S83-88.